# Using Leaflet layer control not accepting two L.control

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geocoding

I am using a `L.control.search` to search for points in GeoJSON file and create a layer with the points I´m seaching according to a features.properties.value, and dispay them on a map.
The var that creates de layer with the points is:

```
var lights= L.geoJson(data, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.type === "Lights");
  },
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng) {
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 3, 
        fillOpacity: 1, 
        color: 'black', 
        fillColor: '#E0E0E0', 
        weight: 1,})
    },
    onEachFeature: setPopup
}  
); // end geojson layer all lights
lights.addTo(map);
```

Than I add a layer group and pass it to `L.control.search` to be able to search using `feature.properties.maclora`

```
var allLayers = L.layerGroup([lights]);

L.control.search({
    layer: allLayers,
    initial: false,
    propertyName: 'maclora',
    zoom: 20,
    buildTip: function(text, val) {
        var type = val.layer.feature.properties.maclora;
        return '<a href="#" class="' + type + '">' + text + '<b>' + type + '</b></a>';
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

But when I try to use another `L.Control` that searches for addresses the `L.control.search` disapears:

I´m using `https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js` to create another control and search for streets names and add a marker to it.

```
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder({
        defaultMarkGeocode: true
    })
        .addTo(map);
```

How can I create something similar to a `L.Control.Cluster()` and add the controls to it?

Comment: Hi TomazicM, I have refrased my question. Yes I want to create another control to search for street names and add a marker to it. But when I do so, the L.ControlSearch. disapears from the map.

Comment: Where is `L.control.search` coming from? Please edit your question and add that info.

Comment: Hi TomazicM, just edit my question.

Comment: For me it works without problems. I tested with Leaflet 1.6.0 and 1.9.3.

Comment: What I find strange is, if I duplicate de L.control.search it shows in the map. But If I set L.Control.geocoder it doesn´t.

Comment: Which version of Leaflet are you using?

Comment: 1.9.3. I manage to have both, but I figured that what makes the L.Control.search disapears is the the var groupedOverlays ={}. 
It happens when I add that line of code. The L.Control.geocoder remains. And I wanted to have a L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays, options).addTo(map), with var options = {groupCheckboxes: true}....